# Servlet Exception Jersey 1.8

Tags: java, servlets

I have a webservice runnig and I am getting the following error.

```
Apr 25, 2014 6:28:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

My Libs are at a mininum:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>google</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

I've read differnt solutions, but none seem to work, I cleared out any other libraries that might affect this.

Comment: This looks a bit like you are mixing versions of class libraries that do not fit to each other. See the description of AbstractMetodError: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html